# Graphical modeler in QGIS 3.0.3 - Access Vector Field in Calculator

Tags: field-calculator, qgis-3, qgis-modeler, vector-field

I want to create an algorithm with the graphical modeler in QGIS 3.0.3 where i define one Vector Layer and a Vector Field from this Layer as my inputvariables. Then i want to access the field-values in the field calculator. For example:
formula in fieldcalculator:

```
($area/1000000) * INPUT_FIELD
```

But this won't work. The fieldcalculator doesn't know or can't access the field values.

When i use an algorithm and define the INPUT_FIELD as an input-variable it works, but i can't access the field-values in the calculator.

How can i acess the field-values from my input Vector Field in the fieldcalculator?

Answer (score 4):

I found that, in QGIS 3.4 at least, QGIS is touchy with parenthesis and spaces

This should work:

```
( $area / 1000000 ) * INPUT_FIELD
```